# Relation between Volume and Surface Area of Sphere

Tags: calculus

The volume of the sphere is increasing at the rate of $6\,\mathrm{cm}^3/\mathrm{hr}$. At what rate is its surface area increasing (in $\mathrm{cm}^2/\mathrm{hr}$) when the radius is $50\,\mathrm{cm}$?

The supposed answer is $0.24$.

There is a choice of $0.36$ and I'm getting that.
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 6
\\R = 50
\\S = 4\pi r^2
\\V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
So I put

$$V = S\cdot\frac{r}{3}
\\\frac{dV}{dT} = \frac{50}{3}\cdot\frac{dS}{dT}
\\6 = \frac{50}{3}\cdot\frac{dS}{dT}
\\\frac{dS}{dT} = 0.36$$

Is the problem set wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: Recheck your formula for the surface area.

Comment: sorry. typo. changed it still getting same result @JohnJoy

Comment: You've made a mistake in calculating $\frac{dV}{dt}$. Note that when $V$ is changing, $r$ is changing too. So $\frac{dr}{dt}\neq0$. Also remember that $\frac{d(rS)}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}S+r\frac{dS}{dt}$.